# CSS: Span is partially obeying the css applied to it

Tags: css

I have been trying to get a success message to appear on the center of my website.
What I tried applies to all the website except from a sector called "featured products."

When adding something to my wishlist the message appears to be "following" the product rather than being in the middle of the screen and fixed.

I attach a screenshot for details.

CSS Code

```
.flag-message {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: fixed;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 17px;
    width: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* height: 170px; */
    background-color: rgba(68, 68, 68, 0.72);
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    padding: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
    font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif;
    /* font-weight: 700; */
    z-index: 9999949;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide you code.

Comment: The css you provide is fine (https://jsfiddle.net/mtvs05q9/), so you have a problem before or after. Can you provide the full code ?

Comment: @Mat This is a drupal view. My theme is on bootstrap. I notice something without being sure that this is wrong. I have 3 after pseudoelements with clear:both and display:table. This though seems to me like bootstrap's normal behaviour.

Comment: Maybe the problem is caused by the ancestor of this span that has `transform` property, and that stops its `position:fixed` from functioning (see Issue 1 in the CSS Transforms spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#issue-fc114988)?

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn This solution worked great for me, problem solved. I had a pulse effect on the product box creating this mess.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that your "product" may have position:relative, so that your top: 50% and left: 50%, is following relatively to your product rather than your wrapper/site?